# Scaling data in R - I need to scale a dataframe avoiding the first 9 columns, but the final scaled file needs to have the first 9 columns

Tags: r, merge, scale

I have a dataframe with first 9 columns as identifying information of the individual records - information I will use to aggregate later

However that dataframe needs to have the rest of the columns scaled to do cluster analysis

I scaled using (names made up for illustration)

```
dfscaled<-scale(df[-9])
```

the dataframe has 43 columns and over 4M rows.

I need to join the scaled back to the original df[10,43]

how do I do this because the dfscaled doesn't have a key column label in the merge function

Help please!   Thank you very much for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use cbind or bind_cols (dplyr):

```
data.to_scale<-raw_data [,10 :NCOL(raw_data)]
scaled_data<-scale(data.to_scale)

scaled_data_complete<-cbind(raw_data [,1:9], scaled_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!   I'm struggling understanding where I insert my df (original file) and the dfscaled (scaled file with scaled data columns but not the first columns) in to your code there?   Can you elaborate?

Comment: @DataScienceDave raw_data = df